# Is it possible to get the view count on specific url from Cloudflare GraphQL Analytic API

Tags: cloudflare

I've tried searching for this for a while but still haven't found any thread talking about this yet I know I could use some GA or make a custom page-view tracking on the backend sided but the reason why I needed to go with the Cloudflare GraphQL Analytic API because if it possible then I would have all the viewer count from the past also because my website already have Cloudflare in the first place

Thank you